# jQuery each() only being called once

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have multiple radio groups that have multiple selection restrictions, one is by name attribute and the other is with jQuery.  For each radio group, I'm setting checked attributes to false on change so only one radio can be checked per group.

HTML

```
<div id="radio_group">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="0"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="0"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="0"/>Phone
</div>
<div id="radio_group">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="1"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="1"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="1"/>Phone
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#radio_group').each(function(){
    var mainElement = $(this);
    mainElement.children('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
        mainElement.children('input[type=radio]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

This only works with the first group, any suggestions?

EDIT:

Used class selector instead of id:

HTML

```
<div class="radio_group">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="0"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="0"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="0"/>Phone
</div>
<div class="radio_group">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="1"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="1"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="1"/>Phone
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.radio_group').each(function(){
    var mainElement = $(this);
    mainElement.children('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
        mainElement.children('input[type=radio]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: "The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element" http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Id 's` is unique.You can use same class name for any no of elements but you can not use same id for more than one element

```
<div id="radio_group" class="className">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="0"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="0"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="0"/>Phone
</div>
<div id="radio_group" class="className">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="1"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="1"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="1"/>Phone
</div>


$('.className').each(function(){
    //write logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div classs="radio_group">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="0"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="0"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="0"/>Phone
</div>
<div class="radio_group">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="1"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="1"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="1"/>Phone
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.radio_group').each(function(){
    var mainElement = $(this);
    mainElement.children('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
        mainElement.children('input[type=radio]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

You can't have `id` repeated

Answer (score 0):

`ID` are unique identifier. So when using jQuery `#` selector, it return only 1 object.

Use class instead and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have same ID multiple times. Its not Html complaint. you can use same class and use `. selector` to select all the divs